# Boundary conditions for an infinite line charge and grounded conducing plane

Tags: electrostatics, charge, potential, boundary-conditions, method-of-images

[image]

I'm not asking for a solution to the problem, I'm confused about what I should set the boundary conditions to, it's obvious that $V=0$ at $z=0$ because of the grounded $xy$ plane, but I don't know what to do with the other boundaries, the problem is that the line charge itself extends to infinity parallel to the x-axis, so I feel like it isn't right to assume that $V$ goes to zero as $s$ goes to zero, not like the case of a point charge where $V$ actually goes to zero away from the charge, so what should I do?

**edit:** One fix I thought about is to assume that $a >> d$ where $a$ is the reference point of the potential of the line charge since the charge extends to infinity and $d$ is the distance between the line and the $xy$ plane parallel to the x-axis, then set the boundary conditions as $V=V(y.z)$ where $V=\frac{\lambda}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} ln(\frac{s_{-}^{2}}{s_{+}^{2}})$, neglecting the potential produced by the grounded plane, is that reasonable?

Comment: Do you know the solution for the line charge replaced by a point charge ?

Comment: I know the analogy with a charged sphere that is equivalent to a point charge at the center, but for the line charge, I don't recall.

Comment: This is the general method : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_image_charges